# Mocking an object that is created inside a method

Tags: unit-testing, junit, powermockito

**Method to be tested**:

```
public class myclass{
public void findFile(final String directoryName, final DataImportMonitoringCronjobModel job)
    {
        File file = new File(directoryName);
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            final Date archiveDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
..}
}
```

How do I create mock for file object from my test class and satisfy the if condition?

I tried with the PowerMockito, but unable to satisfy the if condition.

**Test Class**

```
@Mock
private File file;
@Test
public void findFileTest() throws Exception
{
    
    PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(file);
    PowerMockito.when(file.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);
    myclass.findFile();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What's the `file` you're returning from the test? Why not just mock the `isDirectory` method?

Comment: I am returning file that i have mocked using @Mock (edited) isDirectory is a method of File.class. So we should instantiate tie object first to use the method isDirectory

Comment: And why not mock isDirectory?

Comment: and how do we do it? I am new to writing test cases, and this could really help.

Comment: I think that's covered in most any PowerMock/PowerMockito tutorial since that's one of the things it does.

Comment: I tried to use powerMockito as below, when i try to debug, in findFile() method, file.isDirectory() condition is not satisfied even when i tried to mock in test class using powerMockito as below

_@Test
    public void findFileTest() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(file);
        PowerMockito.when(file.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);
  }_

Answer (score 0):

Why mocking?
Use real temp files/directories for you test.

JUnit5 has @TempDir

JUnit4 has @Rule TemporaryFolder

This way you can get real file/folder, provide it in you method and then check what happens after.

Comment: Because mocking the method is faster than actual file io, there's no need for an actual file, and if you need to modify the date you'll end up mocking anyway.

Comment: Not always. e.g. PowerMock is very very slow, and in a lot of cases working with real files will be even faster.

Comment: I'd like to see benchmarks showing how manipulated bytecode is slower than disk access if you have any.

Comment: Can you please help me how to use @Rule TemporaryFolder in the above case?